# why my search form not do the search at first time?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, search

It is quite wired that my search form not  work at the first time, you need to search again to do the real search, is there something wrong in my code?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6wpV/4/)

**HTML**

```
<form id='sform' action="/admin/search.php" method="get">
    <input id="search" placeholder="Enter your group name..." type="search" name="s" value="" />
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/*search bar*/
 #sform {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#search {
    border: 4px solid #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#search:hover {
    border-color: #199ed9;
}
#search:focus {
    border-color: #199ed9;
    outline: none;
    width: 180px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#search.searching {
    margin-left: 80px;
    width: 10px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#search + p {
    background: #999;
    content:'';
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -22px;
    width: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: center 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center 20px;
}
#search + p:hover, #search:hover + p, #search:focus + p {
    background: #199ed9;
}
#search.searching + p {
    -moz-animation: rotateHandle .6s linear 6;
    -webkit-animation: rotateHandle .6s linear 6;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateHandle {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateHandle {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    }
}
/*end of search bar*/
```

**JS**

```
$(function (){
//expand search bar
var okToSubmit = false;
$("#sform").submit(function (e) {
    if (!okToSubmit) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#search").addClass('searching').val('');
        var url = $(this).attr('action');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                timeout: 8000,
                success: function (r) {
                    $("#search").removeClass('searching');
                }
            });
            okToSubmit = true;
        }, 8000);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: The code you have given has `okToSubmit == false` by default, so will not submit, of course.

Comment: your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bdf8V/

Comment: why you are using setTimeout??

Comment: Yea, I want to check the in searching effect (rolling around) work or not

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in ajax. A in Ajax means **Asynchronous**. You cannot guarantee the order of execution or you cannot guarantee that the ajax request will be completed within 8 seconds.

Also, `okToSubmit` should be in success handler and do this instead of what you are doing:

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#sform').serialize(),
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function (r) {
            $("#search").removeClass('searching');
            okToSubmit = true;
        }
    });
    setInterval(doAjax, 8000);
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
$(function () {
    //expand search bar
    var okToSubmit = false;
    $("#sform").submit(function (e) {
        if (!okToSubmit) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#search").addClass('searching').val('');
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            doAjax();
        }
    });
});
```

This will guarantee that one request will be completed before doing the second request.

If you are using jquery version less than 1.8, you can add `async:false` attribute to your `$.ajax({});`

Comment: what if async: false, added ?

Comment: there are some problems in your solution. you are accessing $(this).serialize() in doAjax() function which is not in scope. secondly assigning var url in submit handler and using it in doAjax. what is this ???

Comment: i did not understand how your solution 'will guarantee that one request will be completed before doing the second request' as you stated.

Comment: @AhsanShah, once the request takes place, the interval of 8 seconds and again you call the same function. So it goes on like that.

Answer (score 0):

it is working in your provided fiddle. however, you need to remove `.val('')` call which is emptying the value before submitting.

```
    var okToSubmit = false;
    $("#sform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!okToSubmit) {
            $("#search").addClass('searching');
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    timeout: 8000,
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert('search result:'+ r);
                        $("#search").removeClass('searching');
                        okToSubmit = true;
                    }
                });
            }, 8000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to handle the search results in ajax success handler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following work now:

```
    $("#sform").submit(function (e) {
                    $("#search").addClass('searching');
                    var url = $(this).attr('action');
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: url,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            timeout: 8000,
                            success: function (r) {
                                    $("#search").removeClass('searching');
                            }   
                    }); 

    });
```

Comment: so you removed the setTimeout. what else??

Comment: @AhsanShah and the e.preventDefault()

Comment: no, it is not work, since the data is not passed to the page `/admin/search.php`; on the other hand, if I use `e.preventDefault()`, then it can't direct me to the results page `/admin/search.php` although the data has passed to it.

Comment: It work now, need to remove the `val('')` as your were noted before.